# Checking a box by label or index with a variable in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a form that automates tasks on a page by user input but I'm having trouble interacting with an element on the page. It's a CheckBoxList with dynamic names and number of elements. The HTML looks like this:

```
    <ol id="ratingModification_SupplierContact_content">

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="searchQuery.vehicleGroups[0].isSelected" value="on" class="vehGrp">&nbsp;abcd ef (ghi)</label> <br>

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="searchQuery.vehicleGroups[1].isSelected" value="on" class="vehGrp">&nbsp;jklm no (pqr)</label> <br>

                </ol>
```

Where " abcd ef (ghi)" is the label of the first checkbox.

I already have a button that extracts the labels from the elements and puts them in an array designed with help from users here:

```
    var vehicleGroupInputElements = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));

    var vehicleGroupNames = vehicleGroupInputElements.Select(f => f.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))).Select(f => f.Text).ToArray();
```

And I populate my form's CheckedListBox with:

```
    vehicleGroupList.Items.AddRange(vehicleGroupNames);
```

But when I try to send the user selection back to the page I run into issues. I have tried selecting based on index via IndexOf() and the ClassName but can't figure out the syntax to make it work. Failed example:

```
    foreach (int userChecks in vehicleGroupList.CheckedItems)
        {
            int checkIndex = vehicleGroupList.Items.IndexOf(userChecks);
            var checkTarget = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));
            checkTarget.IndexOf(checkIndex).Click();
        }
```

Which won't compile because int checkIndex cant convert to an IWebElement. I have also tried to build a string to address the index with xpath but it can't find the element or  throws a no compound names exception. Failed example:

```
    foreach (int userChecks in vehicleGroupList.CheckedItems)
        {
            int checkIndex = vehicleGroupList.Items.IndexOf(userChecks);
            string elementTarget = "searchQuery.vehicleGroups[" + checkIndex + "].isSelected";
            var checkTarget = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format("//option[contains(text(), {0}]", elementTarget))).Click();
        }
```

I've also tried to find the element by label via xpath similar to the above but it never finds it. What is the correct way to find the elements and check them?

Comment: Do you want to sequential click on each checkbox?

Comment: I think that would work. I was intending to 'foreach(checked item on my form) click the corresponding checkbox on the page'. But clicking them all at once works, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked into Xpath syntax and found the answer. With the help of Chrome's 'copy Xpath' function in inspect mode, I found the path needed and successfully clicked the input element.

Example Xpath of the first input is as follows (notice the HTML for label[index] is 1 more than the way C# would count.)

```
    //*[@id="ratingModification_SupplierContact_content"]/label[1]/input
```

And solution as follows

```
    //Retrieves the checked items from the form and sends them to the page.
        foreach (object checkedItem in vehicleGroupList.CheckedItems)
        {
            //Gets the index of the checked items.
            int checkedIndex = vehicleGroupList.Items.IndexOf(checkedItem);
            //Adds 1 to the index to match format of the page HTML.
            checkedIndex++;
            //Puts the index+1 into a string.
            string indexText = checkedIndex.ToString();
            //Finds the element by index+1.
            var clickTarget = Builder.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[@id='ratingModification_SupplierContact_content']/label[" +indexText+ "]/input")));
            clickTarget.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to click on each checkbox you can use :

```
var vehicleGroupInputElements = Builder.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vehGrp"));

foreach (IWebElement checkbox in vehicleGroupInputElements)
{
    checkbox.Click();
}
```

Comment: Just tried, compiles but also just checks all the boxes in on the page.

Comment: And that is not what you want? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: 1) I populate a CheckedListBox in my form with all the items in a webpage's CheckBoxList. (works)
 2) A user checks one or more boxes in the form. (works) 
3) The user checked items are checked on the page. (does not work yet)